# Trying to run Node.js container on docker: "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 11: exec: .: Permission denied"

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I've been stuck with that for a while and all other solutions I tried do not give me any good results.

I'm running docker on Windows 11.

Here is how my Dockerfile currently is:

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /home/node/app

USER node

COPY --chown=node:node package.json .

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "js/main.js"]
```

And it still gives me a permission error!
I'm out of ideas and my friends do not know how to help me either.

Comment: Mind showing us `docker-entrypoint.sh`? Line 11 would be nice...

Comment: Also an explanation of how docker-entrypoint.sh gets run could help. I see it being copied to the machine but nothing shows how it's being run (what user its being run as would be important here).

Comment: The problem is that I can't even open the VM terminal through docker.
I am not running docker-entrypoint, I just try to run my container and it just throws me that error.

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple problems that need solutions. If you're not calling `docker-entrypoint.sh` then why are you copying it to the machine?  What IS calling it? Are you using docker-compose (you can specify a different entrypoint that overrides a dockerfile)?

Comment: I'm not using docker-compose, I do not call it anywhere. Looks like the docker-entrypoint.sh file is inside the VM because I'm not copying it to there (at least not knowingly).

Comment: I see. I confused your RUN command for a COPY command. It is present in the `node` image. [Here's the file that the image is running](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docker-entrypoint.sh). Maybe knowing it's contents can help you out.

Comment: I will try to access it somehow, tomorrow I will answer because I have to take care of other code here, thanks for your attention!

Comment: Tried to access the terminal, but I still need to run the container, which throws this:
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 11: exec: .: Permission denied

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 11: exec: .: Permission denied

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 11: exec: .: Permission denied